# WPF application startup ( or DBContext initialization) slow with strict firewall setting

Tags: asp.net, wpf, entity-framework

The WPF application is a local client application, and the running environment has a very strict firewall setting, even not able to connect to Microsoft domain. When I start the WPF application, it takes a long time(90 seconds) to startup. However, **if I plug out the internet cable, it starts up very fast**(6 seconds).

By debugging the application, I found out the Entity Framework DBContext initialization takes most of the time. It is executed right at the moment of the application starting.

I have already done the following:

```html
<runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```

But that doesn't help. Anybody else met this problem before? Please help me out...

Comment: If you computer's network name is in the connection string you should try to replace it by `(local)` (if this is SQL Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got a answer: The .net framework ask for certificate revocation list when the application starts and there exists a internet connection. However, the firewall block the request. See more:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2303.understanding-access-to-microsoft-certificate-revocation-list.aspx